# On my website the big image at the top isn't resizing on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I really hope to find out why my big image that I use at the top of my page is not resizing it just zooms in on my iPhone, please go to www.buyyopage.com and see what I'm talking about. It's a photo of a responsive type logo you'll see it under my navigation bar and above my content, the website is in beta mode I put it up so you guys can take a look

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code , check your css file and if media query not there then try this **MEDIA QUERY**

```
 

       .image_tag {
            position: fixed;
            // your css for image tag
            ...
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
             header 
            {
              position: absolute; 
            }
        }
```

This Works 100% .